# Stuck on How to Display Hover Data in Specific Format

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I am testing some plotly code here.

```
import plotly.express as px
# find business profits
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
df_gains = df_rev_exp[((df_rev_exp.ltd_spending) < df_rev_exp.REV2)]
df_gains.tail()

# scatter plot of losses
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(df_gains, x="site_name", 
                 y="gain_or_loss", 
                 color="gain_or_loss",
                 size='REV2', hover_data=['site_name','REV2'])
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=325)
fig.show()
```

Everything plots just fine but the REV2 is pretty large, and as such it is hard to read when I hover over the data points in the chart. I'm trying to figure out a way to show numbers as millions.  For instance, In would like to see 1.25M and not 1257789.84, which is what I am seeing now.  I tried playing around with `fig.update` but I couldn't get anything working.  How can I modify the formatting on these plotly charts?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Plotly `4.14.3` and this version shows `2.2M` straight out of the box when the source is `x=[10000000, 22000000, 34000000]`:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=[10*10**6, 22*10**6, 34*10**6],
                          y=[10,12,14]))
fig.show()
```

[image]

So two things come to mind:

1. Update Plotly.
2. Check that you're inputting your values as values and not strings

Comment: @ASH You're welcome! What worked though? Updating or making sure your numbers weren't formatted as strings?

Comment: My version of plotly was a bit out of date. I think updating the library partially worked. I had floats before, so that wasn't the issue. Now, though, one of my columns is showing as 2.6M and another is showing as 2684991. Weird.